# How to construct quality long sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I want to construct long sentences, for fiction. I do use subordinate conjunctions and coordinate conjunctions, and I also understand different kind of phrases, and grammatical rules. But I still struggle to string the phrases and clauses together in an effective way. **Are there any tips to construct long sentences? And really make it beautiful** (***By arranging different grammatical elements in different ways***). (I don't like semicolons, and i don't want to use it). Give me examples too. I will understand better.

Comment: This question might be better suited to https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/30561/.

Comment: I think this question is probably too broad for ELL.

Comment: I see that this has since been cross-posted: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/37540/how-to-construct-quality-long-sentences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to learn this is simply to read well written books. Once you have mastered the building blocks (listed in your question), read glorious prose.

I would concentrate on slightly older books that people still read, or books that have won prizes like the man booker prize, or the womens prize for fiction.

Best seller lists aren't very reliable as indicators of quality writing.

But be warned there is a good middle ground between

> This is Paul. Paul has a ball. Paul likes the ball

and Dickens (from a tale of two cities) I once remember trying to read Dickens and one whole page was a single sentence.

> It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of
>   wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it
>   was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the
>   season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of
>   despair, we had everything before us, we had nothing before us, we
>   were all going direct to Heaven, we were all going direct the other
>   way – in short, the period was so far like the present period, that
>   some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for
>   good or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only.